# Measuring peaks and the distance between them in my plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I will keep the explanation, how my codes works, very short. I advise you to try this code yourself, so perhaps you understand it better that way. I have an audio-file and read it in my code. Now i switch from the time domain to the frequency domain by using the function FFT. But the only difference is, that i am performing an STFT on my audio signal. I do it every 30ms, until to the length of my signal. I am aware, that there are many different function in matlab, which also can perform this easily, but there are not giving me the results i need. Now, i am plotting many different frequency spectrums every 30ms. But i split up my signal in three frequency bands. They are called LOW, MEDIUM and HIGH. Basically, this means I have 3 different spectrums plotting every 30ms. The next step I do, is summing all the magnitudes from ONE frequency spectrum together, this means I have ONE VALUE per frequency spectrum, which are being squared.

Now, i have the power from every spectrum ! And all of these values are being plotted in my code. I am only plotting the power values, otherwise my code performance time would be extremely slow.

Btw, the code looks long, but there are two for loop. In the first, i read the low spectrum and when it is finished, the second starts with the medium and high spectrum. Basically they are the same. I am aware, i can probably do that with findpeaks or something similar. But how can i write/pull that of? Or what the necessary steps to do that. At the end, i included a file, Hopefully you can see that.
I want to measure the peaks and get the distance between them from the red plot.

**EDIT:**
Ok, i got the peaks, but not in the way i imagined. I want to show the peaks, which are above 5000-line. Sorry for not being clear at the beginning. See my plot, what i mean. I want to say my code, that only the peaks should be measured, which are above the 5000-line.

```
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(ValuesOfYc); 
p=plot(x,ValuesOfYc,'r-' ,x(locs), pks,'ob');
```

This is, what I did above, in my first loop. How should i go on from there?

```
clear;
clc;
%% MATLAB
%% read file
%_________________________________________
[y,fs]=audioread('Undertale - Megalovania.wav');
% audioread = read wav -file
% y = contains the audio signal
% fs = 44100
% 'UnchainMyHeart' = name of the wav-file
%_________________________________________
%% PARAMETER FOR STFT
%_________________________________________ 
t_seg=0.03; % length of segment in ms
fftlen = 4096; %FFT-Points

% Defining size of frequency bands
f_low= 1:200;    %lower frequencies
f_medium= 201:600;  %medium frequencies
f_high= 601:1000; %higher frequencies
%__________________________________________
%% CODE

segl =floor(t_seg*fs); 
windowshift=segl/2; 
% defining the size of the window shift
window=hann(segl); 
% apply hann function on segment length (30 ms)
window=window.'; 
% transpose vector
si=1; 
% defining start index
ei=segl; 
% defining end index

N=floor( length(y)/windowshift - 1);
% Calculates the number, how often the window has to shift
% until to length of the audio signal

f1=figure;
    % Generating new window

      f=0:1:fftlen-1;
      f=f/fftlen*fs;
      % defining frequency vector

      Ya=zeros(1,fftlen);

      ValuesOfYc = NaN(1,N);
      ValuesOfYd = NaN(1,N);
      ValuesOfYe = NaN(1,N);

      x =(1:N)*windowshift/fs;
      % defining x-axis

for m= 1:1:N 

      y_a = y(si:ei);
      % a segment is taken out from audio signal length(30ms) 
      y_a= y_a.*window;
      % multiplying segment with window (hanning) 
      Ya=fft(y_a, fftlen);
      % Applying fft on segment
      Yb=abs(Ya(1:end/2)).^2;  
      % Squaring the magnitudes from one-sided spectrum

          drawnow; % Updating the graphical values

      figure(f1);
      % Showing the power values

      %% frequency bands

      y_low = Yb(f_low);  % LOW frequency spectrum

      Yc=sum(y_low);
      % Summing all the power values from one frequency spectrum together
      % so you get one power value from one spectrum 
      ValuesOfYc(m) = Yc;
      %Output values are being saved here, which are generated from the for
      %loop
      % m = start variable from for loop


      [pks, locs] = findpeaks(ValuesOfYc);

      subplot(2,1,1)
      p=plot(x,ValuesOfYc,'r-', x(locs(pks>=5000)), pks(pks>=5000),'ob');  
      p(1).LineWidth =0.5;
      xlabel('time (Audio length)')
      ylabel('Power')
      grid on

      si=si+windowshift; 
      % Updating start index 
      ei=ei+windowshift; 
      % Updating end index

end

for o= 1:1:N

      y_a = y(si:ei);
      % a segment is taken out from audio signal length(30ms) 
      y_a= y_a.*window;
      % multiplying segment with window (hanning) 
      Ya=fft(y_a, fftlen);
      % Applying fft on segment
      Yb=abs(Ya(1:end/2)).^2;  
      % Squaring the magnitudes from one-sided spectrum

          drawnow; % Updating the graphical values

      figure(f1);
      % Showing the power values
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
      %% frequency bands

      y_medium = Yb(f_medium); % MEDIUM frequency spectrum
      y_high = Yb(f_high); % HIGH frequency spectrum

      Yd=sum(y_medium);
      Ye=sum(y_high);
      % Summing all the power values from one frequency spectrum together
      % so you get one power value from one spectrum 
      ValuesOfYd(o) = Yd;
      ValuesOfYe(o) = Ye;
      %Output values are being saved here, which are generated from the for
      %loop
      % m = start variable from for loop

      subplot(2,1,2)
      p=plot(x, ValuesOfYd,'g-', x, ValuesOfYe,'b-' );
      p(1).LineWidth =0.5;
      xlabel('time (Audio length)')
      ylabel('Power')
      grid on

      si=si+windowshift; 
      % Updating start index 
      ei=ei+windowshift; 
      % Updating end index
  end
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you probably need `findpeaks`. But you also need to shows us that you made an effort.

Comment: Your line: `p=plot(x,ValuesOfYc,'r-' ,x(locs), pks,'ob');` should be altered to `p=plot(x,ValuesOfYc,'r-' ,x(locs(pks>5000)), pks(pks>5000),'ob');` to just get those points which are greater than 5000

Comment: @Wolfie, i already tried that, but it still gives me peaks, below the 5000 line.

Comment: I don't see how... please post that image / code

Comment: I am sorry, i knew what the mistake was now. You weren't wrong.